# Как корректно пересобрать jsPlumb при изменении DOM в Vue

Tags: vue.js

С помощью Vue из объекта циклом выводятся на экран блоки. Простите за длинный пример, но не знаю, как еще упростить, чтобы воспроизвести проблему.

```js
var blocks1 = [{
    id: "b1",
    pos: [20, 100],
    routes: [{
      id: "r1",
      target: "b2"
    }, {
      id: "r2",
      target: "b3"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "b2",
    pos: [130, 50]
  },
  {
    id: "b3",
    pos: [130, 150]
  }
];

var blocks2 = [{
    id: "b4",
    pos: [25, 110]
  },
  {
    id: "b5",
    pos: [120, 60],
    routes: [{
      id: "r3",
      target: "b4"
    }, {
      id: "r4",
      target: "b6"
    }]
  },

  {
    id: "b6",
    pos: [135, 140]
  }
];

var jsp = jsPlumb.getInstance({
  Container: "jsp",
  Anchors: ["Right", "Left"]
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blocks: blocks1
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log("vue mounted");
    drawLines();
    makeDraggable();
  },
  updated: function() {
    console.log("vue changed");
    drawLines(); //рисуем связи заново
    //makeDraggable(); почему работает без этого?
  },
  methods: {
    changeData: function() {
      jsp.reset(); //сбрасываем jsplumb
      this.blocks = blocks2; //меняем данные
    }
  }
});

function makeDraggable() {
  let blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
  for (var block of blocks) {
    jsp.draggable(block.id);
  }
}

function drawLines() { //перебираем маршруты
  let routes = document.querySelectorAll(".route");
  for (var route of routes) {
    drawLine(route);
  }
}

function drawLine(route) { //рисуем связь
  jsp.connect({
    source: route.id,
    target: route.dataset.target
  });
}
```

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.jtk-endpoint {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="jsp">
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="changeData">change data</button>
    <div class="block" v-for="block in blocks" :id="block.id" :style="{top:block.pos[1]+'px', left:block.pos[0]+'px'}">
      <div class="title">{{block.id}}</div>
      <div class="routes">
        <div class="route" v-for="route in block.routes" :data-target="route.target" :id="route.id">
          {{route.target}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.11.2/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Есть jsPlumb, который после отрисовки DOM в хуке `mounted()` делает эти блоки перетаскиваемыми и рисует между ними связи. Пока все хорошо, все работает.

Теперь я хочу загрузить другую схему блоков и меняю объект. Я сбрасываю jsPlumb методом `reset()`, Vue перерисовывает новые блоки, jsPlumb заново рисует связи, но, при перетаскивании блока *b5* с исходящими связями все ломается.

Выдает в логе:

> jsPlumb function failed : TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined

Как это исправить?

И еще вопрос, почему заново нарисованные блоки становятся перетаскиваемыми? Такое ощущение, что Vue не стирает их полностью, а меняет содержимое у такого же количества блоков, оставляя эвенты.

UPD: да, так и есть, vue просто меняет id и содержимое блоков, вместо того, чтобы удалить их из dom и создать заново. Как изменить это поведение?

Полный пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/talleyran/pen/abodqYo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Vue действительно не перерисовывает блоки полностью. Поэтому на них остаются эвенты и классы от jsPlumb. Чтобы заставить Vue полностью перерисовывать блоки нужно ему сказать, что они разные, добавив атрибут `key` явно.

```
<div v-for="(block,index,key) in blocks" :key="block.id" ... >
```

Значения должны быть уникальными, например id, тогда Vue поймет, что это разные блоки.

```js
var blocks1 = [{
    id: "b1",
    pos: [20, 100],
    routes: [{
      id: "r1",
      target: "b2"
    }, {
      id: "r2",
      target: "b3"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: "b2",
    pos: [130, 50]
  },
  {
    id: "b3",
    pos: [130, 150]
  }
];

var blocks2 = [{
    id: "b4",
    pos: [25, 110]
  },
  {
    id: "b5",
    pos: [120, 60],
    routes: [{
      id: "r3",
      target: "b4"
    }, {
      id: "r4",
      target: "b6"
    }]
  },

  {
    id: "b6",
    pos: [135, 140]
  }
];

var jsp = jsPlumb.getInstance({
  Container: "jsp",
  Anchors: ["Right", "Left"]
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    blocks: blocks1
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.clear();
    console.log("vue mounted");
    drawLines();
    makeDraggable();
  },
  updated: function() {
    console.log("vue changed");
    drawLines(); //рисуем связи заново
    makeDraggable(); //возвращаем перетаскивание
  },
  methods: {
    changeData: function() {
      jsp.reset(); //сбрасываем jsplumb
      this.blocks = this.blocks==blocks1 ? blocks2 : blocks1; //меняем данные
    }
  }
});

function makeDraggable() {
  let blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");
  for (var block of blocks) {
    jsp.draggable(block.id);
  }
}

function drawLines() { //перебираем маршруты
  let routes = document.querySelectorAll(".route");
  for (var route of routes) {
    drawLine(route);
  }
}

function drawLine(route) { //рисуем связь
  jsp.connect({
    source: route.id,
    target: route.dataset.target
  });
}
```

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.jtk-endpoint {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="jsp">
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="changeData">change data</button>
    <div class="block" v-for="(block,index,key) in blocks" :key="block.id" :id="block.id" :style="{top:block.pos[1]+'px', left:block.pos[0]+'px'}">
      <div class="title">{{block.id}}</div>
      <div class="routes">
        <div class="route" v-for="route in block.routes" :data-target="route.target" :id="route.id">
          {{route.target}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.11.2/js/jsplumb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```